# Line Break in Richtextbox accordind to width of richtextbox

Tags: vb.net, richtextbox, word-wrap

I'm having trouble with RichTextBox.

```
If RichTextBox1.TextLength > RichTextBox1.Width Then
Environment.NewLine ..... FOR EACH LINE UNTIL END
```

I'm trying to have words wrap when there isn't enough space for a line.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?  If so, could you provide details on what you've done that hasn't worked?  Also, why do you need to do this?  The `RichTextBox` should word wrap for you.

Comment: @NazimIqbal :  So, if the richtextbox is resized bigger then the text inside wont fit anymore ?

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried:

```
     RichTextBox1.WordWrap = True
```

Does that do what you want to happen, or do you need something else to happen?

HTH